# Sencha Touch Reading XML data

Tags: xml, sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs, xmlreader

I have just recently started working with Sencha Touch 2.0. I am having problem in reading XML data. I started with basic "getting started" app which comes with the download and it is working fine which means I have done the setup correctly. Now I have made some changes to read simple XML but I am not able to see any data on screen. Below is my code. Please help me with this. - 
here are the contents of app.js file -

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'lib/touch/src'
});

Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'email']
    }
});

var mystore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'userData.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            rootProperty: 'users',
            record: 'user'
        }
    }
});  

Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {
        //The whole app UI lives in this tab panel
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',   
            items: [
                // This is the home page, just some simple html
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    cls: 'home',
                    scrollable: true,
                    html: [
                        '<img height=260 src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
                        '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
                        "<p>Building the Getting Started app</p>",
                        '<h2>Sencha Touch (2.0.0)</h2>'
                    ].join("")
                },


                {
                    xtype: 'list',
                    title: 'Events',
                    iconCls: 'star',
                    itemTpl: '{id}',                     
                    store: mystore                    
                }


            ]
        });
    }
});
```

The XML is at the same location as this app.js file. Please note that I have not installed any server. I just make changes to app.js and open "index.html" in chrome browser.

Here is the XML. It is same as the one given on Sencha Docs.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
<user>
    <id>112</id>
    <name>Ed Spencer</name>
    <email>ed@sencha.com</email>
</user>
<user>
    <id>248</id>
    <name>Abe Elias</name>
    <email>abe@sencha.com</email>
</user>
</users>
```

Here is my code after changes -

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'lib/touch/src'
});


Ext.regModel('Personal', {
    fields  : [
        'id',
            {name: 'name',  type: 'string'}, 
            {name: 'email', type: 'string'}
    ]
});


Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {
        //The whole app UI lives in this tab panel
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',   
            items: [
                // This is the home page, just some simple html                                                

            {
                xtype   : 'selectfield',
                name    : 'user',
                label   : 'Users',
                store   : new Ext.data.Store({
                            model       : 'Personal',
                            autoLoad    : true,
                            proxy       : {
                                type    : 'ajax',
                                url     : 'userData.xml',
                                reader  : {
                                    type    : 'xml',
                                    root    : 'users'
                                }
                            }
                        }),
                valueField  : 'name',
                displayField    : 'name'
            }


            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: getting frustrated now!!..been trying since morning but no luck...docs and guides are also very brief not helping much....Adobe Flex documentation is far better and very easy to understand....:-(((

Comment: ***Very Important - On sencha forums one guy asked me what does the console say - here is what it says - XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/sencha%20trials/userData.xml?_dc=1340003241745&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ...I guess this is what the problem is. Checking now how to solve this...Pls post here in case you know the solution..Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, My problem solved...Chrome doesnt allow local file access through Ajax...I installed web server XAMPP..and executed the code..and it worked...I am sooo happy...do stay in touch...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @GordanWebb try this for show data from XML file,

```
Ext.regModel('Personal', {
    fields  : [
        'id',
            {name: 'name',  type: 'string'}, 
            {name: 'email', type: 'string'}
    ]
}), {
        scroll  : 'vertical',
        items   : [
            {
                xtype   : 'selectfield',
                name    : 'user',
                label   : 'Users',
                store   : new Ext.data.Store({
                            model       : 'Personal',
                            autoLoad    : true,
                            proxy       : {
                                type    : 'ajax',
                                url     : 'userData.xml',
                                reader  : {
                                    type    : 'xml',
                                    root    : 'users'
                                }
                            }
                        }),
                valueField  : 'name',
                displayField    : 'name',
            }
        ]
    }
```

This example show data on `selectfield` element Sencha. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: thanks for yur response....but after these changes app is not loading...I am totally new Sencha....I replaced my model definition with yurs and in place of list I added yur selectField code....is it correct? ...I even tried with "store" definition as a part of my list component rather than declaring it outside, the way I have done above....but no progress....the problem is I am unable to figure out what I have done wrong....I have gone through XML-Sencha questions on stackoverflow as well..

Comment: mmmno I think you're doing something wrong. Please show me how do you doing.

Comment: hello..I have posted the changes in edit...please look above...thanks again for your response...:)

Comment: ***Very Important - On sencha forums one guy asked me what does the console say - here is what it says - XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/sencha%20trials/userData.xml?_dc=1340003241745&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ...I guess this is what the problem is. Checking now how to solve this...Pls post here in case you know the solution..Thanks :)

Comment: Hello, My problem solved...Chrome doesnt allow local file access through Ajax...I installed web server XAMPP..and executed the code..and it worked...I am sooo happy...do stay in touch...:)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use a web server (easyphp or wamp) (xamp on linux and MacOS) and access to you app throw the localhost/yourAppDirectory, everything will be alright